# displaying in a UITableView CoreData objects ordered in a Set

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsset

I have difficulties displaying objects coming from CoreData in a tableView.
I have 2 sorts of entities : `Sample` and `SampleList`. What is important to know is that a `SampleList` has an attribute `sampleSet` which is a set of samples (entity of Sample)

First I succeeded in displaying every `SampleList`. Here is `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SampleList" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastSampleDate" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[sortDescriptor release];
[sortDescriptors release];

NSError *error;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
// Handle error
}

[self setSampleListArray:mutableFetchResults];
[mutableFetchResults release];
[request release];
```

Once I click on a row in my tableView, I would like to display in another `UITableView` every sample from the `SampleList` selected.

I thought that I could pass to the subview `SampleList mySampleList`. But then, I don't know what to do with it as it is not organized. 
How can I return an ordered array of `Sample` (ordered by `dateSample` attribute for example) ?

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `NSSet` and `NSArray` methods on `sampleSet` to get an ordered array:

```
sortedArray = [[sampleSet allObjects] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

or if you want to specify particular sort descriptors instead of the regular "compare" method:

```
sortedArray = [[sampleSet allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: It worked ! that was fast actually. But I don't understand why I had to retain sortedArray (which is declared in the .h)